# KeyError 'City' in Dataframe when Calculating Value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geolocation, geopy

I've been having some trouble working with a dataframe in Python for the past couple of days - I've been trying to calculate the coordinate values for a 'City' Column in my dataframe (it has around 10500 rows, however I always receive a KeyError: 'City' when I try to run any functions on that column.

### Background

I've been inputting a .csv file which contains around 10500 rows x 15 columns and converting it to a dataframe. I'm then adding an additional column at the end called 'Coordinates' to hold the coordinate values of the 'City' column.

```
#inserting my .csv file to convert to a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/test.csv")

#creating new column 'Coordinates' to insert into dataframe at the end
df['Coordinates'] = '0,0'

# practice location finding using geopy
geolocator = Nominatim(timeout =10)

#method to calculate latitude and longitude
def eval_results(x):
try:
    return (x.latitude, x.longitude)
except:
    return (None, None)

#calculating the coordinates value by running the following methods on the 'City' column
df['Coordinates'] = df['City'].apply(geolocator.geocode,
timeout=1000000).apply(lambda x: eval_results(x))
```

### Error

However, when I run the code, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metadata-geo.py", line 27, in <module>
metadata_df['Coordinates'] = metadata_df['City'].apply(geolocator.geocode,timeout=1000000).apply(lambda x: eval_results(x))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'City'
```

I'm not entirely sure what the error is, and I've been going through a lot of posts concerning KeyErrors, but none of them seem to apply to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

This means the column "City" **doesn't exists**.

Could this might be "city" ?

Otherwise, you can check columns names by typing :

```
print df.columns
```

(I see python 2.7)

or

```
print(df.columns)
```

for python 3+

and then chose the column you want

Comment: I printed the columns and this was the output I received: `Index([u'Identifier\tModel\tUserID\tCountry\tProvince/State\tCity\tFloor Area [ft2]\tStyle\tNumber of Floors\tAge of Home [years]\tNumber of Occuapants\tHas a Heat Pump\tAuxiliary Heat Fuel Type\tNumber of Remote Sensors\tfilename\tCounted Number of Remote Sensors\tCoordinates', u'Coordinates'], dtype='object')` As you can see, the 'City' column exists, so I'm not sure why I'm still receiving a KeyError?

Comment: You got the wrong separator, use the option : sep = "\t" in read_csv and this will be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, I was using opening the file without separating the columns, so I was missing the `sep='\t'` when reading the CSV file.